# Populating select element with external javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to popluate a dropdown box from a list of data from my js file. I've found a few examples out there but not exactly what I'm trying to do. I would like it to show 'DataText' in the drop down itself.

```
 <select id="select" </select>
```

script

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/data/datafile.js"></script>
```

Could it not be done as simple as this?

```
    $(document).ready(function()
{
      $("#select").append(Mydata);​
});
```

file format

```
var Mydata=[{"ID":"00","DataText":"Text1"}, {"ID":"01","DataText":"Text2"}, {"ID":"02","DataText":"Test3"}]
```

Comment: No, you should iterate through the array, create option elements and then append them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('#select').html(function(){
   return $.map(Mydata, function(v) {
      return '<option id='+ v.ID +'>'+ v.DataText +'</option>';
   }).join('');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Y8eCy/

Answer (score 0):

Sure it can be done, but you have to iterate over the data and add what's needed.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 0, count= Mydata.length; i < count; i++) {
        $('<option>').val(Mydata[i].ID).text(Mydata[i].DataText).appendTo("#select");
    }
});
```

This is a quick solution, so add error checking. Also, just in case this isn't a bad paste job, the HTML provided is invalid. The opening select tag needs a `>`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hpS2E/)

Comment: I get a Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL  on the  $('<option>') line on my end.

Comment: I saw something similar in jsFiddle and fixed it by removing the last character, which happened to be a red dot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop your data and then insert it into your select, in this case i needed to parse the data.

```
var Mydata='[{"ID":"00","DataText":"Text1"}, {"ID":"01","DataText":"Text2"}, {"ID":"02","DataText":"Test3"}]';

var data = $.parseJSON(Mydata);

    $.each(data, function(k,v){
     $('#test').append('<option value="'+v.ID+'">'+v.DataText+'</option>');
    });
```

Working example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpuEV/)

Comment: getting a unexpected token 'o' at line 1 of html file.

Comment: In your external file make your MyData as a string, var Mydata='[{"ID":"00","DataText":"Text1"}, {"ID":"01","DataText":"Text2"}, {"ID":"02","DataText":"Test3"}]';

Comment: or remove the $.parseJSON